# Strip out while(1) prepended to JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, frontend

I am making an ajax get request, but receive back a JSON object prepended with while(1) eg.

```
while(1);{"servers":[{"some_data": data, "etc":...}]}
```

We just started doing this to prevent malicious attacks, but I am not sure how to strip it out so that I can parse the JSON properly.

here is the function I am using for the $.get call

```
function myFunction() {
    $.get('/v1/servers').success(function(data) {
      data.servers.forEach(function(server){
        presentServer(server);
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = ajaxResponse.responseText;
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(text.replace('while(1);', ''));
```

Another way without using replace:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(text.substring(text.indexOf(';') + 1);
```

Updated with your function:

```
function myFunction() {
    $.get('/v1/servers').success(function(response) {
      var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText.substring(text.indexOf(';') + 1));
      data.servers.forEach(function(server){
        presentServer(server);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: @MikeSamuel `String.replace()` can take either a regex or a value to replace. I'm using a string to replace, not a regex

Comment: yes - it's often assumed that the string argument to `String.replace` is converted to a regex, but in fact `String.replace(RegExp, String)` and `String.replace(String, String)` work quite differently

Comment: hm, I am still getting 
while(1);{"servers":[{"some_data": data, "etc":...}]}
as a response

Comment: You'll still get it as a response, make sure your variables are named correctly. What you receive back from ajax ("response" in my code) and the parsed object ("data") are different. Can you post your code with my changes?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard XSS protection feature. Since you have tagged the question with jQuery, you should be able to do this:

```
$.get('/your/api.json', function (resp) {
    var json = resp.substring(resp.indexOf(";")+1)),
        data = $.parseJSON(json);
    // do other things

});
```

with the code that you have posted above:

```
function myFunction() {
    $.get('/v1/servers').success(function(resp) {
      var json = resp.substring(resp.indexOf(";")+1)),
      data = $.parseJSON(json);
      data.servers.forEach(function(server){
        presentServer(server);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: I just posted my function, do I just need to add in the 'var json = ' line?

Comment: yes you need only add the first two lines of my callback and it should fit right in.

Comment: hmm, do you mean pass it in to the .get request? I'm not seeing a change

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your example code. I neglected to mention that I was using `resp` for the initial response, which is parsed to `data` after we preprocess it

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring to strip your leading characters:

```
JSON.stringify(response);
response.substring(9,response.length);
```